# Setting up a private local tor network

Tags: configuration, linux, error, ssl, private

Im trying to set up a fully localised private tor network as a degree project to prove that this network topology can be used within the private business sector to secure internal traffic. I have set up 2 middle relays, an exit relay and a certificate authority all running on ubuntu 14.04...i have also for testing reasons got a client machine with windows 7 and tor client installed and a windows server 2016 acting as a webserver.

When turning on my tor relays and checking the log files i find that they are all 100% bootstrapped and running but when i check arm (relay monitoring tool) it tells me that "connections died in state connecting with SSL state (No SSL object). Have searched high and low for any information that can help but there is very little on even just creating my own tor network, and troubleshooting...even less.

Would someone please be able to help.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Sounds fun......it would be a cheap solution to a lot of corporate problems.

My guess would be that you need more redundancy, which will be hard to do without adding more computers of all types.

You should also try after you set up your local network to creating a "MasterNode Rendezvous" point for your local traffic to hop onto the real internet, but not allowing any incoming traffic directly to each node except through your MasterNodes.  Also not every computer in your local network needs to be connected to the Internet via the MasterNode for more secure.

You can isolate or expand as much as you like.  But ultimate unless they are strictly Accounting/Office/Engineering work computers they will need connected to the internet if your business model revolves around workers posting to social media ect.........or using dropbox.

But ultimately you could instead of dropbox instead of using MasterNodes to sync with the regular internet only sync with other Local Tor Networks you have set-up.  This way they can act as a hidden services over the regular network wires instead of using drop box.

Comment: redundancy isnt my issue, i can easily do that in a virtual environment and have 5 middle relays all running off a host machine. i dont want my tor network to even touch the real internet. i think my problem is the certificate not being installed from my Certificate Authority, as i was thinking about it today. as it is openssl ca im using, and have created certificates, but not installed them and verified them as self signing certificates, ssl wont work and will kill the connection, if someone can verify my theory, then id appreciate it

Comment: the topology my fellow students are devising consist of a cloud based interface, a high availability web server, linked to a high availability fully encrypted datacenter, our aim is to prove that a file thats encrypted from the data center can move from the data center, through the web server through ftp...but still be encrytped...and then through the internal network being fully encrypted the entire way...thats our goal